# Keys of a hash whose values sum to a particular value

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash:

```
a = {"Q1"=>1, "Q2"=>2, "Q5"=>3, "Q8"=>3}
```

I want to retrieve a set of keys from it such that the sum of their values equals a certain number, for example 5. In such case, the output should be:

```
Q2 Q5
```

Please help me on how to get this.

Comment: Why `Q2 Q5` not `Q2 Q8`?

Comment: This is the *subset sum* problem, which is NP-complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def find_combo(h, tot)
  arr = h.to_a
  (1..arr.size).find do |n|
    enum = arr.combination(n).find { |e| e.map(&:last).sum == tot }
    return enum.map(&:first) unless enum.nil?
  end
 end
```

```
h = {"Q1"=>1, "Q2"=>2, "Q5"=>3, "Q8"=>3}

find_combo(h, 5)   #=> ["Q2", "Q5"] 
find_combo(h, 2)   #=> ["Q2"] 
find_combo(h, 6)   #=> ["Q5", "Q8"] 
find_combo(h, 4)   #=> ["Q1", "Q5"] 
find_combo(h, 8)   #=> ["Q2", "Q5", "Q8"] 
find_combo(h, 9)   #=> ["Q1", "Q2", "Q5", "Q8"] 
find_combo(h, 10)  #=> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity:

```
hash = {"Q1"=>1, "Q2"=>2, "Q5"=>3, "Q8"=>3}
arr = hash.to_a

1.upto(hash.size).
  lazy.
  find do |i|
    res = arr.combination(i).find do |h|
      h.map(&:last).sum == 5
    end
    break res if res
  end.tap { |result| break result.to_h if result }  
#⇒ {"Q2" => 2, "Q5" => 3}
```

Comment: I believe `combination` suffices. Why `lazy`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland of course, `combination`, thanks, updated. `lazy` to do it one by one, stopping on the first one. In a case of `combination` it might be redundant, but I keep adding `lazy` where it belongs as a matter of a good habit.